# How can there be an edge from white node to gray node (Tree edge) in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

If there is such an edge, then, it means the white node is the parent node and gray node is discovered while scanning the adjacency list on white node, which in turn will make the white node, gray.

There can only be back nodes from white to gray nodes, according to me. If someone can clarify, where am I going wrong.

**EDIT**

WHITE node: Undiscovered node

GRAY node: Discovered, but not yet closed.

Comment: What are the definitions of white/grey node?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic edited the question, please see again.